# Why is MnSO4 colourless?

Tags: ionic-compounds, color

I get it that transition metal salts have colour due to d-d transition from $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ to $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbitals in octahedral and the opposite in tetrahedral but why would $\ce{Mn^2+}$ not have any characteristic colour? Is it so because the orbitals are degenerate in $\ce{MnSO4}$? or because d-d transition only takes place when there is completely empty d orbital?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I improved the formatting of your post by using MathJax for chemical formulae. For more information on how to do so yourself, check out the [help], [this meta-post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444). And there are [even more hints](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3044) available.

Comment: I'm already a member at this site. Thank you @Jan

Comment: @Jan Because this email is unregistered. I am Quark.

Comment: It does have a colour, but it is very faint. It has to do with the selection rules governing d-d transitions in a metal complex: http://wwwchem.uwimona.edu.jm/courses/selrules.html in particular the $\Delta S = 0$ rule.

Comment: @orthocresol Could you elaborate the selection rules here in a simple language for me to be able to understand?

Comment: @orthocresol Oh I got the reason. So there must be no electron with same spin in that orbital, to which the electron is being transited to? Right? Because if it were present it should have opposite spin which will violate Hund's rule?

Answer (score 4):

Manganese(II) sulphate is not colourless. It is a faint pink. Compare this image taken from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Manganese%28II%29-sulfate-tetrahydrate-sample.jpg), where a full list of authors is available:

[image: Manganese(II) sulphate tetrahydrate]

However, it is true that the colour is rather faint, and you need a white background to properly see it. That’s because manganese(II) is a $\mathrm{d^5}$ system and a high-spin one of those meaning that all five d-orbitals are occupied by a single electron:

[image: d5 high-spin]

Exciting an electron directly is forbidden due to the spin-retaining rule: The excited electron must occupy an already populated orbital, which is only possible if it flips its spin, which is forbidden by selection rules. Special mechanisms are needed to account for the (obviously possible but faint) transition here; the page Orthocresol linked in the comments names spin-orbit coupling.

Comment: So basically, the orbitals should be empty for transition to take place,right?

Comment: @user29557 Not necessarily. For example if you added one more spin down electron to the lower level, then that electron could be promoted to the upper level, as long as it retains its spin state in the upper level (no change in spin).

Comment: @orthocresol Oh. So, if we had 8 electrons, there would be a characteristic colour, right?

Comment: @user29557 Indeed - so an example of an 8-electron ion would be $\ce{Ni^2+}$, and $\ce{NiSO4}$ has what I personally think is a very pretty colour (there's a picture on Wikipedia).

Comment: @user29557 $\ce{Ni^2+}$ is a typical $\mathrm{d^8}$ system, so yeah.

Comment: What is spin orbit coupling?

Comment: @user29557 Frankly, I have no clue. ^^' Could be the basis of a good question …

Comment: @user29557 Quantum mechanical coupling of two angular momenta (orbital angular momentum $L$ as well as spin $S$) to form one larger angular momentum. Don't worry about it.